# How to select name with the highest power and highest salary

Tags: mysql

How to select name with the highest power and highest salary

| Id | Name | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kobe | 50000 |
| 2 | Lebron | 500099 |
| 3 | Steph | 628228 |
| 4 | Thompson | 50505 |
| 5 | Shabu | 393828 |

Comment: You could order the table base on salary and select just the name column and limit your results to just one single row. How this looks like will depend on your database system you are using.

Comment: How can you show the query

Comment: Showing your attempt would be encouraged. Also, tag your dbms (oracle, mysql, sql server, etc).

Comment: Its mysql sorry for that can you'll help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTE represents your table. The query you need is the last 3 lines, where it's sorting the output by salary in descending order, then limiting to 1 row.

```
with salaries as (
  select 1 as id, 'Kobe' as name, 50000 as salary union all
  select 2, 'Lebron', 1000000 union all
  select 3, 'Steph', 222222
  )
select name
from salaries
order by salary desc limit 1
```

Output:

```
Lebron
```

**UPDATE**

Per your comment about using a Max function, here's one way, using a sub-query:

```
select name
from salaries
where salary = (select max(salary) from salaries);
```

Comment: Can you only use aggregate function?

Comment: Sure, will update..

Comment: Its doneee thankyou very much for your good answer

Comment: If this provides a solution, then please consider marking as approved. Also, the reason for needing the dbms is due to variance in query language. For example, oracle does not support `limit`.

Comment: How im new here in stackoverflow? Btw can you  make 2 condition in your query?

Comment: Hey can you make 2 condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to to so

```
SELECT 
t.name
FROM <your_table_name> t
WHERE t.id = 
(SELECT 
t1.id 
FROM 
<your_table_name> t1
ORDER BY t1.salary
DESC LIMIT 1);
```

*EDIT*

Or you can just use

```
SELECT 
t1.name
FROM 
<your_table_name> t1
ORDER BY t1.salary
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Its perfect but can you use aggregate function only, its mysql

Comment: Answer edited, See now

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on 53RT's comment, for MySQL:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you use aggregate function only?